# Python + Selenium: Insert new value to drop-down menu

Tags: python, selenium

How do I insert a new option from a Bootstrap drop-down using **Python** and  Selenium?

```
<select type="select" class="selectpicker form-control" id="selFoo" >
    <option data-hidden="true">Make a selection</option>

    <option value="Foo">1</option>
    <option value="Bar">2</option>
    <option value="Baz">3</option>

    <option value="MY OPTION">1000</option> #my own option
</select>
```

Comment: Could you add some additional information to your question, such as what you have tried etc. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I only manage to retrieve and select the options, but now i need to add new ones

Comment: @CelsoXavier, so, it it possible to do this by real user actions? Thanks.

Comment: If you use the Inspect on Chrome you can change the options value